# React Native Expo Notification

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I currently have a project thats being developed with EPXO RN. There is a need for push notifications and alerts in my app especially when the app is backgrounded / foregrounded.

I 've looked at several options and haven't really decided which one to choose yet. However, going through the Expo Notifications API, i've got a questions:

From my understanding there are two ways to send Alerts:

1. `Expo.Notifications.presentLocalNotificationAsync(localNotification)`
                                     or
   `Expo.Notifications.scheduleLocalNotificationAsync(localNotification, schedulingOptions)`
2. POST request to `https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send` using a token after permission has been granted

Can some one explain the difference in between these two?

Comment: I guess the main difference is #1 is for creating notifications locally, from the app code. (You have some logic running in the app and you want to show a notification without comunicating with your backend) And the #2 is for sending notifications from your backend server/website (Something happened on your server/database, and you must send a notification to the user through expo to his/her app)